# Mysql: How to query with if else condition inside if

Tags: mysql

I'm getting trouble to query my data. I do not know where to start with query if else condition inside if.

Problem is:
How to query if its **type = cpm** and **end_date < now()** then change result value type to **before**, and if its **type = cpm** and **end_date > now()** then change result value type to **after**.
I have a data in table, result as below :

[image]

And I want to get 
result as below :

```
Array(
  [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [type] => free
            [end_date] => 2013-06-20
        )
  [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [type] => after
            [end_date] => 2013-08-29
        )
  [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [type] => before
            [end_date] => 2013-06-20
        )
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: look at date() function in php and compare

Comment: Hi @FaceOfJock, yes I know it, if use php if else, but I want to use it at mysql query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ah ok sorry i tought you use php

Comment: Okay, no problem, yes it's use PHP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
select 
  id, 
  case 
    when (type = 'cpm' and end_date < now()) then 'before' 
    when (type = 'cpm' and end_date > now()) then 'after' 
    else type
  end as type, 
  end_date
from my_table;
```

Comment: Hi Mr Vinodadhikary, thanks for your help, working now, thanks sir.

Answer (score 2):

You could use MySQL `CASE` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case

```
CASE
WHEN `type` = 'cpm' AND `end_date` < NOW() THEN 'before'
WHEN `type` = 'cpm' AND `end_date` > NOW() THEN 'after'
ELSE `type`
END as `type`
```

Comment: I think you might've added an extra `CASE` to the end... Just sayin.

Comment: @jerdiggity not according to the docs - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html  -> `The CASE statement ... is terminated with END CASE instead of END`

Comment: @jerdiggity you are correct, I was looking at the the wrong docs, the ones for stored procedures, not the case expression. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case

Comment: yep you're right... But that is freaking weird. Makes me wonder if I've been doing it wrong the whole time, or...? Either way, something's out of place because I get an error on my machine.

Comment: Hi Mr Sean, thanks for your help, working now, working with your answer and answer Mr Vinodashikary. thanks sir.

Comment: Ohh OK. Thought I was going crazy for a second. But at least it's worked out... Everybody wins.

Answer (score 2):

You can use WHEN .. CASE for this .

Here is Link for your solution  [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cb94/6)